# How to call a method from base class with variable from base class?

Tags: c#, oop, class, variables, inheritance

I want to call a method from my base class that also has a variable from the base class:

```
    class BaseClass
    {
    public string BaseClassMethod()
    {
        if (CheckKeyboard(Keys.Up))
            return "Up";

        if (CheckKeyboard(Keys.Down))
            return "Down";

        if (CheckKeyboard(Keys.Enter) && keyboardOn == true) <-- keyboardOn is a variable from my BaseClass that i want to be able to use :/
        {
            counter = 0; <-- counter is also one of those variables
            return "Enter";
        }

        return "";
    }
    }

    class InheritFromBase : BaseClass
    {
    public string Update()
    {
        currentKeyboard = Keyboard.GetState();
        currentMouse = Mouse.GetState();

        if (BaseClassMethod() == "Up")
            if (selected > 0)
                selected--;
            else
                selected = buttonList.Count - 1;

        if (BaseClassMethod() == "Down")
            if (selected < buttonList.Count - 1)
                selected++;
            else
                selected = 0;

        if (BaseClassMethod() == "Enter")
            return buttonList[selected];

        previousKeyboard = currentKeyboard;
        previousMouse = currentMouse;

        return "";
    }
    }
```

and since i call the mothod from another class it seems like a cannot access he variables (values) and then change them.
please help :) thank you

Comment: Are the member variables marked as `private`? If you're trying to access `counter` in your `Update` method, make sure it is `protected`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally bad practice to expose a local variable outside a class. You can do it through a [protected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) access modifier, however I'd recommend you expose it through a `protected` Property or Method.

assuming `keyboardOn` is your class-level variable in your base class:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    private bool keyboardOn;

    protected bool KeyboardOn;
    {
        get
        {
            return this.keyboardOn;
        }
    }    
}    

public class InheritFromBase : BaseClass
{
    ....

    if(this.KeyboardOn)
    {
        // do something based on base property
    }

    ....
}
```

The above assumes you only want to `get` the status variable `keyboardOn` from the base class. If you need to also set the value of the variable from the inheriting class you can add a `set` to the exposing property.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `protected` [access modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to allow access to the variable from derived classes.

For example:

```
protected bool keyboardOn = false;
```

OR

You could make them public properties of the base class like this:

```
 public bool KeyboardOn { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make those variables global and accessible in your base class by making them either public (don't) or write a getter method that returns it (do). Then in the inheriting class, do: `MyBase.getVariable()` to get the variable or `MyBase.function()` to call a function in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a public getter in your super class like so:

```
public bool isKeyboardOn() {
    return keyboardOn;
}
```

This way you don't have to expose the variable, and unlike setting the variable to protected, you don't risk the variable being changed by any other classes.

Comment: Why not use a protected property with getter only. Better structure in my opinion as Methods tend to describe more complex functionality, whereas Properties are simple accessors.

Comment: @KP. That works as well. I see you've edited your answer accordingly, so that answer is already covered, I'll keep this one as an alternative.

Comment: yes you made a good point on the get/set. I first assumed the inheriting class would need get/set but safer to assume less and open up as needed as you said.